# Setting width of tabs in android.support.design.widget.TabLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am using tabs for my Viewpager, and this is the XML right now:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

They look great but I want to be able to have more tabs and not have everything squish on the screen. However I don't like switching to scrollable tabMode because then everything flattens out and looks messy. How can I set the width of the individual tabs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TabLayout does not provide the attributes for particular tab's fixed width.
But you can set min and max width.

> tabMinWidth and tabMaxWidth

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: So if I set min and max width to the same thing is this the same as setting the width directly?